# Which RAM to buy for mid 2010 15 Inch Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, upgrade, memory, hardware-recommendation

I am looking to upgrade my 15 inch macbook pro from 4GB to 8GB of RAM. I have never upgraded anything on a macbook before and I am wondering how important is the specific RAM that i purchase? I read in a couple places than only OWC and Crucial RAM works with my macbook pro. Is this correct? Or can i buy any two DDR3 1066Hz 4GB RAM and just slot it into my Macbook Pro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The brand shouldn't really matter. I have G Skill in mine with no problems. The stock was Samsung. The trouble with that specific model is that it doesn't clock down faster RAM properly thanks to some hardware bug with the Nvidia chipset. It's very important to only use 1066 MHz DDR3 with this model (you can usually get away with faster on other models). I had 1333 MHz RAM for a while and I had kernel panics all over the place.

The actual specifications are [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1270#link2):

> - Double Data Rate Small Outline Dual Inline Memory Module (DDR3) format
> - 30mm (1.18 inch)
> - 2 GB or 4 GB
> - 204-pin
> - PC3-8500 DDR3 1066 MHz type RAM

Answer (score 0):

http://www.crucial.com has an app you can download to tell you which you need. Kingston & Corsair have drill-down selectors, but Crucial's is far easier.